# Why does Mozilla browser launched from Aptana 3 studio is not able to resolve the video file kept at the same location as that of .html file?

Tags: aptana

I'm trying out a simple video tag example in HTML5, using Aptana 3 Studio IDE.

The following is my code,

HTML5 Video Player

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="360" poster="big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" controls="controls">
  <source src="trailer_test.ogg" type="video/ogg"> </source>
</video>
```

I'm able to see the poster "big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" getting displayed when I run the HTML file from Aptana 3 studio (configured to launch the Mozilla Firefox). But it is not able to play the video "trailer_test.ogg". Can someone please tell me what is going wrong here?

But when I run the HTML file separately using Mozilla, the video file does play. My question is why the video is not playing when Mozilla is launched from Aptana 3 Studio?

Thanks,
Prem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Aptana Studio's built-in webserver does not respond correctly on the content type of .ogg file. The issue has been fixed in 3.0.3 (nightly builds, but about to be released). The temporary workaround is to use other local webserver (e.g builtin Apache on Mac). See launch configuration setting for using external webserver.

Regards,
Max

Comment: Thanks Max. will wait for the updated release and also in the meanwhile try configuring the Aptana settings to use external web server.